# Reference request: AI for mathematicians

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for books on AI and Machine Learning written for PhD + level Mathematicians. Is there anything like this?

Thanks,
Vladimir

Comment: Maybe there is a unified approach to all those algorithms from the point of view of probabiliy theory/statistics when all machine learning are just special cases of a general theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of learning algorithms are basically [empirical risk minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_risk_minimization).

You may want to look at "Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms" by Shalev-Shwartz and Ben-David, which is suitable for masters level students or Mohari's "Foundations of Machine Learning".

Devroye's A Probabilistic theory of Pattern Recognition is more intended for an applied mathematician audience (late undergrad/early grad) as is Vapniks' The Nature of Statistical Learning Theory. Books on concentration of measure like Lugosi, Massart and Bucheron's Concentration Inequaliaties text are useful too.

There are a bunch of graduate courses on statistical learning theory out there as well, such as [this](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~tewari/LT_SP2008.html), [this](http://nowak.ece.wisc.edu/SLT09.html), [this](http://maxim.ece.illinois.edu/teaching/fall15b/index.html) and others.